# Ionic3 deep linking issue: Controller being loaded twice

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

I recently updated my Ionic 2 project to version 3. Everything works as expected, except for the deep linking part.

I use the split pane provided by Ionic, and therefor I have a split pane service, which manages the navigation stack. In the home controller, I subscribe to this service, and call setRoot() or push() of my view child accordingly:

```
    this.rootSubjectSubscription = this.splitPaneService.rootSubject$.subscribe((pageWithContext: PageWithContext) => {
      console.info(`Displaying ${JSON.stringify(pageWithContext)} with setRoot`);
      console.info('tester:', pageWithContext.page.name);
      this.contentCtrl.setRoot(pageWithContext.page, pageWithContext.data);
    });

    this.pushSubjectSubscription = this.splitPaneService.pushSubject$.subscribe((pageWithContext: PageWithContext) => {
      console.info(`Displaying ${JSON.stringify(pageWithContext)} with Push`);
      this.contentCtrl.push(pageWithContext.page, pageWithContext.data);
    });
```

When I navigate to the root app page (http://localhost:9999), there is no problem.

When I navigate to the link to home directly (http://localhost:9999/#/nav/n4/home), however, the home controller is loaded twice. This generates two subscriptions, and errors because setRoot is called twice.

I think this is due to the fact that in my app.component.ts, I have the following code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import { AuthService } from '../providers/auth-service';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class Switchboard {
  rootPage: any;

  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen, private _auth: AuthService) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
    });

    const authObserver = _auth.subscribe((state) => {
      console.info(this.rootPage);
      if (state) {
        this.rootPage = 'home';
      } else {
        this.rootPage = 'auth';
      }
    });
  }
}
```

In the auth observer, I navigate to the home page if a user is logged in (which is expected behavior). Some way, when I navigate directly to the home page, this controller is loaded twice (by the deep linking provider and by the auth observer).

Is there any way to circumvent this?

Comment: Where in the home controller you call this subscriptions? And does this subscription can send the user to the home page again?

Comment: I’ve tried the constructor, ionViewDidEnter, ionViewDidLoad; they’re all called twice

Comment: anyone find the solution?